# Posting Data from Ionic App to PHP-File on Webserver via POST wont work

Tags: php, rest, ionic-framework, mysqli

right now im trying to send datat from my ionic app to a php-file which should use that data for a MySQL-statement. unfortunately the file cant access the data and since im kinda new to HTTP-Requests i dont know why. As far as i can see the request is a valid one.

Below u can see my php code.

i Hope you can help

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, 
OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth- 
Token');

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$argument = json_decode($_POST["argument"]);


$mysqli = new mysqli(//DB connection is set here);
$query = $argument;
$dbresult = $mysqli->query($query) or trigger_error($mysqli->error . " 
            [$query]");


while ($row = $dbresult->fetch_array()) {

   $json_row = $row['num'];

}

if ($dbresult) {

   $result = $json_row;

} 

else {

    $preresult = "{'success':false}";
    $result = json_encode($preresult);

}


    echo json_encode($json_row);
```

Comment: `$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");` why is this needed? $_POST will have all the posted values.

Comment: So $_POST will get me the needed values, even when im using a http request? saw this line in some tutorials

Comment: You can try without it first.

Comment: i unfortunately still get an empty-query-warning Edit: I tried to use  "if ($_POST)" as a starting condition, but its always set as false, meaning the data cant be retrieved properly

Comment: I don't see a way as to why that would happen. We use input stream when we deal with a webhook. In your case, $_POST should work just fine. Also, why do you send headers before processing of data?